# xmonad same application is appearing on both monitors

Tags: xmonad

I started using xmonad on an Ubuntu box with two monitors attached. When I start xmonad the same layout is duplicated on both monitors. For example: if I have a layout where Chrome and emacs are tiled side-by-side, then I see chrome on the left side of both monitors, and emacs on the right side of both monitors.

Is there a way to say "chrome, go to the left monitor, emacs, go to the right monitor"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it sounds like the view is cloned. There are two steps to fixing your problem:

1. Unclone the views and set them side by side.
2. Learn how to move windows between desktops in xmonad and how to switch desktops.

To unclone, use [xrandr](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2) to set different views for each monitor.

Open a console and type:

```
$xrandr
```

It should display something along the lines:

```
LVDS1 connected 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   1280x800       60.0*+
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1024x768       60.0 +   85.0     75.1     70.1  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        85.1     72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        85.0     72.8     75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
TV1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

In my case LVDS1 is the laptop and VGA1 is a connected projector.

To set the projector left of the monitor use:

```
$xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --left-of LVDS1
```

This will use the default resolution for the projector (in this case 1024x768) and place the view left of the laptop screen.

To set a custom resolution use

```
$xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1280x800 --left-of LVDS1
```

In your case it will be something along the lines:

```
$xrandr --output MONITOR2 --auto --left-of MONITOR1
```

The shortcuts for moving apps between desktops and switching desktops are

Mod Key +  1,2,3, - 9 for bringing the desktop to the monitor the mouse is on

Mod Key + SHIFT + 1,2,3, - 9 for sending the currently focused application to the particular desktop

The default Mod Key for xmonad is Alt but you can [set](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Frequently_asked_questions#Rebinding_the_mod_key_.28Alt_conflicts_with_other_apps.3B_I_want_the_____key.21.29) it to the Windows key in order to free Alt for use in applications.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have not setup [TwinView](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XineramaHowTo) yet? If you follow the link and do that then it will start working correctly; I remember having the same problem. And there are plenty of example configs that work well in multi-headed environments; [like my own one](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Config_archive/Robert_Massaioli%27s_xmonad.hs) for example (though it is meant for Dvorak users).

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is, but you have to enable **xinerama** for this.

Make sure that you have [setup xinerama correctly.](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Frequently_asked_questions#Multi_head_or_xinerama_troubles)