# Dual monitor support in Linux Mint with XMonad window manager?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, xmonad, linux-mint

I'm running Linux Mint 12, and I'd like to configure it to use 2 monitors, each as a separate workspace. Currently the output is mirrored to both screens. In the default window manager, I can set this up by going to Preferences -> Monitors. But I'm trying to use xMonad rather than the default window manager. I read online that the way to configure xMonad to use 2 monitors (without mirroring) is to modify the xorg.conf file. But I don't have any such file...I have a /etc/X11 directory, but no xorg.conf file in it. My graphics card is made by Nvidia, in case that's relevant. Any suggestions?

Comment: For anyone stumbling onto this question here is a longer answer http://superuser.com/questions/330498/xmonad-same-application-is-appearing-on-both-monitors/337689#337689

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by using the "xrandr" program.